# formatting of sections and subsections

Tags: sectioning, subsection

I am new to latex and I want the following formatting style for section and subsections and subsubsections

[image]

I am using following code for section. There is a dot missing after Roman number in output. Also I am not sure how to use for subsections and subsubsections.

```
  \titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\centering}{%
    {\normalfont\thesection}
  }{1em}{}
  \renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
```

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to tweak how the sectioning titles look if you're using a standard document class is to use the titlesec package. I've provided code more or less matching your requirements below, and added comments so you know what each one does.

```
\documentclass{article}

% load the package; make centered titles default
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}

% use Roman numerals for sections
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

% use Arabic numerals for subsections
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

% use letters for subsubsections with a parenthesis
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\alph{subsubsection})}

% put a period and space after numbers
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\thickspace}

% Make section titles centered and bold
\titleformat*{\section}{\centering\bfseries}

% Make subsections centered and italc
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\centering\itshape}

% Make subsubsections centered
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\centering}

\usepackage{lipsum}% provides dummy text; not needed for solution

\begin{document}

\section{This is a Headline}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\lipsum[1][5-6]

\subsection{This is a Subheadline}

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\lipsum[2][5-8]

\subsubsection{This is a Subsubheadline}

\lipsum[3][1-5]

\lipsum[3][6-8]

\end{document}
```

[image: titlesec example]

The package provides more sophisticated commands as well. See [its documentation](https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf).

I also noticed that in your sample, the first paragraph after a title is still indented, unlike LaTeX's normal behavior. The package would also allow you to change that behavior. You could add this to the preamable:

```
% change spacing: not using * means indentation will not be
% suppressed
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*4}{*1.5}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*4}{*1.5}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*4}{*1.5}
```

Yielding:

[image: with no indents]

Again, more details in the documentation.

EDIT: I just noticed that in your original subsubsections, the period is before the parentheses. That complicates things, because you can't use `\titlelabel` consistently then. In that case, you'd have to use the unstarred version of `\titleformat` which provides finer grained control:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[center]{titlesec}

% use Roman numerals for sections
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

% use Arabic numerals for subsections
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

% use letters for subsubsections with a parenthesis
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\alph{subsubsection}}

% Make section titles centered and bold
\titleformat%
    {\section}% command to format
    [block]% overall shape: see documentation
    {\centering\bfseries}% formatting applie to whole thing
    {\thesection.}% format of number label
    {0.5em}% spacing between number label and title
    {}% additional code before title

\titleformat%
    {\subsection}% command to format
    [block]% overall shape: see documentation
    {\centering\itshape}% formatting applie to whole thing
    {\thesubsection.}% format of number label
    {0.5em}% spacing between number label and title
    {}% additional code before title

\titleformat%
    {\subsubsection}% command to format
    [block]% overall shape: see documentation
    {\centering}% formatting applie to whole thing
    {\thesubsubsection.)}% format of number label
    {0.5em}% spacing between number label and title
    {}% additional code before title

\usepackage{lipsum}% provides dummy text; not needed for solution

% change spacing: not using * means indentation will not be
% suppressed
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*4}{*1.5}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*4}{*1.5}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*4}{*1.5}

\begin{document}

\section{This is a Headline}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\lipsum[1][5-6]

\subsection{This is a Subheadline}

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\lipsum[2][5-8]

\subsubsection{This is a Subsubheadline}

\lipsum[3][1-5]

\lipsum[3][6-8]

\end{document}
```

[image: alternative subsubsections]

Comment: Thank you very much @frabjous

Comment: Thanks. Although you've already accepted the answer. I provided some additional info in an edit about how to get subsubsections as `a.)` instead of `a).` as you had it originally. Not sure if that was important to you.

Comment: Thank you very much or providing this detail as well. This was also important to me. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that employs the [sectsty](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package to determine how sectioning headers are displayed (e.g., centered, bold/nonbold etc). It further employs the low-level `\@seccntformat` macro to display how the numbers/letters of sectioning headers are displayed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% First, set the way subsub/sub/sections are numbered:
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\alph{subsubsection}}

% Use method proposed in "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd ed., to determine
% how the section-like counters are displayed in sectioning headers
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
    {\csname the#1\endcsname\space}%    default
    {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}%  enable individual control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\thesection.\quad}       % section
\newcommand\subsection@cntformat{\thesubsection.\quad} % subsection
\newcommand\subsubsection@cntformat{\thesubsubsection.)\space} % subsubsection
\makeatother

% Finally, control the way sectioning headers are displayed
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering\normalsize\bfseries}
\subsectionfont{\centering\normalsize\mdseries\itshape}
\subsubsectionfont{\centering\normalsize\mdseries\upshape}

% Optional: Load `hyperref` package.
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=red]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{This is a Headline}       \label{sec:Head}
\subsection{This is a Headline}    \label{subsec:Head}
\subsubsection{This is a Headline} \label{subsubsec:Head}

Cross-references to section \ref{sec:Head}, subsection \ref{subsec:Head}, and subsubsection \ref{subsubsec:Head}.
\end{document}
```